# URL Routing not working on server in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

Here DataList.aspx & Details.aspx is inside directory v1, so i tried routing in two ways but nothing is working on server.
Global.asax

> ```
> protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {  
>       RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route1",
>                   "Category/{Brand}.html","~/DataList.aspx");
>
>        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route2",
>                 "Category/{Brand}/{Title}.html","~/v1/Details.aspx");
> }
> ```

I am using this routing in hyperlink inside listview. Url is generated correctly, but when i click on link it shows 
"404 - File or directory not found."

I have also added this in web.config

> ```
> <system.webServer>
>     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
>       <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
>       <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,  System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e42" />
>     </modules>    
>     <handlers>
>       <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e42" />
>     </handlers>
>   </system.webServer>
> ```